# Error in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I get below error when  `chain.doFilter(request, response);`  executes. This error occours only sometimes.

Stack trace is below ::

```
enter code here

<i>javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "NULL"
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:516)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:423)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:740)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:835)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:341)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forward(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:261)
    at com.evermind.server.http.GetParametersRequestDispatcher.forward(GetParametersRequestDispatcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:740)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:65)
    at my.SampleFilter.doFilter(SampleFilter.java:120)
    at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindFilterChain.doFilter(EvermindFilterChain.java:16)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:670)
    at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:341)
    at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:816)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:231)
    at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:136)
    at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)</i>
```

My filter code is as below ::

```
<i>public class SampleFilter
implements Filter
{

private transient FilterConfig filterConfig;
Context initialContext;

public SampleFilter()
{
    filterConfig = null;
    initialContext = null;
}

public void destroy()
{
}



public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{



    Connection conn=getJNDIConnection();

    request.setAttribute("CONNECTION", conn);
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Filter start GOOG Website");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Exception occured in doFilter @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        closeConnection(initialContext, conn);
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Connection Closed @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");

        String fullStackTrace = org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e);



        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeConnection(initialContext, conn);
    System.out.println("Filter end ");
}

Connection getJNDIConnection()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        if(initialContext == null)
        {
            System.out.println("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");
        }
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("jdbc/MY_DS");
        if(datasource != null)
        {
            conn = datasource.getConnection();
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to lookup datasource.");
        }
    }
    catch(NamingException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    return conn;
}



void closeConnection(Context ctx, Connection conn) {
    try {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
            ctx = null;
        }

        if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        sqe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn = null;
    }
}

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
    throws ServletException
{
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}
}
</i>
```

My web.xml contents are below ::

```
<i><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>3</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>



  <filter>
     <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>SampleFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class> my.SampleFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SampleFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

     <session-config>
      <session-timeout>720</session-timeout> 
    </session-config>

</web-app>
</i>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's some misunderstanding going here.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "NULL"
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException
```

This exception is not caused by your filter, but it is caused and thrown elsewhere and is never been caught until the `try-catch` block in your filter where you're dealing with the exception in an incorrect manner. You should catch **only** those exceptions which you can reasonably deal with. As there's apparently no one exception which you can reasonably deal with, you should be letting those exceptions go through be removing the entire `catch` block altogether and replace it by a `finally`.

```
Connection conn = getJNDIConnection();
request.setAttribute("CONNECTION", conn);

try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} finally {
    closeConnection(initialContext, conn);
}
```

Back to the particular exception, as said this is caused elsewhere. As the stacktrace is incomplete, I'll do a wild guess: you're somewhere inputting a numeric field with the string value `"NULL"` and it is throwing a `NumberFormatException` on that. The solution for *that* problem should be obvious enough: either don't input a string value `"NULL"`, or make it a string field instead of a numeric field.